# Changing datatype of pandas array from obj to int

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow, keras

I have an array in pandas of dtype 'object', this array only contains integers, but I can't convert it to int32 or any Keras compatible datatype due to the error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

while using the following code:

```
df['label'].astype('int64')
```

This is the column:

```
0        [90, 90, 100, 80, 80]
1        [90, 90, 100, 80, 80]
2      [90, 100, 100, 100, 80]
3         [70, 70, 90, 70, 70]
4        [90, 90, 100, 90, 90]
                ...           
169       [80, 80, 80, 80, 70]
170       [80, 90, 80, 80, 80]
171       [80, 90, 80, 80, 80]
172       [70, 80, 70, 70, 70]
173       [70, 80, 70, 70, 70]
Name: label, Length: 174, dtype: object
```

How can I convert it do an Int dtype?

Comment: The column contains lists as objects. You're trying to convert a list to int which will throw an error

Comment: i read it in the documentation, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.arrays.IntegerArray.html

Comment: No you didn't. You _cannot_ convert a column containing lists to an integer datatype. The whole setup shouts a design problem, too. Why do you not have separate columns for items in the list?

Comment: The whole column is for lists, but i need them to be a ind of list compatible with tensorflow, a list of integers and not strings

Comment: It is a list of integers; there would be quotation marks otherwise

Comment: But why is the dtype object when in the docs is int32

Comment: Have you tried `int([1, 2, 3])`?

Comment: It says cannot convert series to int

Comment: It doesn't work. That's what you're asking for. It's very hard to help you when that's the fundamental issue we're dealing with

Comment: Oh so it's completely impossible? That's some bad new right there, how can i take a list in pandas and make it a tensor that's all I need I don't care about anything else

Comment: Then you'll probably need to take it out of pandas and make a 2d array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can't* have an array dtype in pandas.

However, there are some alternatives, if your end-goal is feeding the dataframe to keras model, you could use something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([[1,2,3]] * 5)
df = pd.DataFrame(s.to_list(), dtype='int64')
```

It's fast and easy to understand.

Then you could use

```py
df.to_numpy()
```

to create a well-formed array of inputs to your model. If you are using tensorflow, you could also use `tf.data` module to achieve the same.

Ask me any additional questions.
Cheers!

Comment: But pandas supports an array of ints and floats: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.arrays.IntegerArray.html
So how can I convert the column in place from `object` to `pandas.arrays.IntegerArray`